# How can I combine three ranges in Google Sheets where there isn't always data in two of them and with a function on one?

Tags: google-sheets

I have three ranges of data from YouTube that I want to combine into a single table. The three ranges are:

- YouTube subscriber numbers by day (the days for the combined sheet will pull from here)
- YouTube videos with lifetime stats and publish date
- YouTube channel statistics by day

I have data for every day on the first--subscriber numbers--going back years. The videos have the publish date, and I want to do a unique count on videos so that they show on the day they were published (so: "How many videos were published on X date?"). And finally, showing the channel stats by day, which don't go back as far as the subscriber numbers, but will be every day going forward.

Here's an example sheet, open for editing  that shows sample data for the three sheets as well as desired output.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ckif5Vo8rLo1HEPUqer7mhyCXfMGlIjdw1wMz6JcPfA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you be open to using [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for this?

Comment: @Iamblichus Sure, though I’ll have to use the same solution in multiple sheets, so standard functions would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project (check inline comments):

```
function GET_COMBINED_TABLE(subscribersRange, videosRange, otherStatsRange) {
  const headers = subscribersRange.shift();
  headers.push("Distinct Count of Video ID by date", ...otherStatsRange.shift().slice(1));
  subscribersRange = subscribersRange.filter(r => r[0]);
  videosRange = videosRange.filter(r => r[0]);
  otherStatsRange = otherStatsRange.filter(r => r[0]);
  videosRange.shift();
  const combinedData = subscribersRange.map(row => { // Iterate through subscribers data
    const rowDate = row[0];
    let videoCount = videosRange.filter(videosRow => videosRow[0] && sameDay(videosRow[0],rowDate)).length; // Check how many rows have this date in videos
    videoCount = videoCount ? videoCount : "";
    let otherStats = otherStatsRange.find(otherStatsRow => sameDay(otherStatsRow[0], rowDate)); // Find same date in other stats sheet
    otherStats = otherStats ? otherStats.slice(1) : new Array(5).fill("");
    return [...row, videoCount, ...otherStats]; // Combine row data from 3 different sheets
  });
  return [headers, ...combinedData]; // Combine headers and data
}


const sameDay = (first, second) => {
  return first.getFullYear() === second.getFullYear() && first.getMonth() === second.getMonth() && first.getDate() === second.getDate();
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function like any in-built one. You just have to provide the appropriate ranges as function arguments:

[image]

#### Note:

If you want to use this function in any spreadsheet without having to add the function to the associated script, consider deploying this as a [Sheets add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/sheets#custom_functions).

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)